# Промо об очереди проверки переведено не полностью

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, очередь-проверок

Во всплывающем окне с подсказкой об очереди [первых ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers) не переведён пункт про другие действия.

> Choose Other action when you have flagged the post or taken other actions, and have finished your review.

[image: всплывающее окно с недопереведённым текстом]

Answer (score 3):

Добавил перевод:

> Choose **Other action** when you have flagged the post or taken other actions, and have finished your review.
> <strike>Выберите **Другие действия**, если вы оставили тревогу под публикацией или предприняли другие действия и закончили проверку.</strike>
> Выберите **Другие действия**, если вы оставили тревогу на сообщении или предприняли другие действия и закончили проверку.
> https://ru.traducir.win/strings/17998

<strike>**Требуется подтверждение для публикации.**</strike>

**UPDATE:** подтверждено. ожидаем публикации.

Comment: По-моему, радио-кнопка там называется **Другие действия**. Во множественном числе.

Comment: @mymedia, да, вы правы. Спасибо за исправление. Поправил перевод в ответе и заменил в traducir